# How to derive effective mass Hamiltonian for a parabolic band

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Starting from the $\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{p}$ -method one can derive the parabolic dispersion for the energy of the conduction band states:

$E(\textbf{k}) = -\frac{\hbar^2\textbf{k}}{2m^*}$

Often however I see this used to justify using a Hamiltonian of the form:

$H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m^*}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

Can anyone tell me how to justify going from the energy dispersion to the operator-form Hamiltonian below? I know that if you insert plane wave states you get the parabolic energy dispersion shown above, but I don't see how this justifies it. I would like it if you could start from the Bloch states or $\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{p}$ equation.